# Display choice from spinner in a textview

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, textview, android-spinner

I have a db and there there are some values i can display in my spinner.. How can i display in a textview what i've choose?

```
 // CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    public void createTable() {
        try {
            mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS " + TABLE
                    + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT, PLACE TEXT);");
            mydb.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errore durante la creazione della tabella",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }

    // THIS FUNCTION INSERTS DATA TO THE DATABASE
    public void insertIntoTable() {
        try {
            mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
                    + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Cibo e Bevande','cibo')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
                    + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Trasporti','trasporti')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
                    + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Svago','svago')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
                    + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Acquisti vari','acquisti')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
                    + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Sanità','sanità')");
            mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE
                    + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('Altro','altro')");
            mydb.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error in inserting into table", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }

    // THIS FUNCTION SHOWS DATA FROM THE DATABASE
    public ArrayList<String> getTableValues() {

        ArrayList<String> my_array = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Cursor allrows = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE, null);
            System.out.println("COUNT : " + allrows.getCount());

            if (allrows.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    String ID = allrows.getString(0);
                    String NAME = allrows.getString(1);
                    String PLACE = allrows.getString(2);
                    my_array.add(NAME);

                    TextView categorietext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sceltelabel);
                    categorietext.setText(NAME); // doesn't work. It display always "Altro"

                } while (allrows.moveToNext());
            }
            allrows.close();
            mydb.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errore.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        return my_array;

    }
```

I tryied with

```
TextView categorietext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sceltelabel);
                        categorietext.setText(NAME);
```

But it display always `Altro` and if i choose something else not change in textview.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  OnItemSelectedListener() in your Activity:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here

   String selecteditem = spinner.getselecteditem().tostring();
   textview.settext(Selecteditem);


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you show using my code? Because i can't do it :( i never use the spinners

Comment: @David_D **there are some values i can display in my spinner** what does this mean? and **How can i display in a textview what i've choose?** From where you choose?

Comment: From the spinner. That it takes the values from the db. (insertIntoTable() method).

Comment: Oh.. Come on david. In previous comment you said you never use spinner? You are showing the spinner in an activity right? In that activity do the above code? What is the big deal with that?

Comment: Ok, i explain better.. this is the example i followed http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/11/18/load-spinner-values-sqlite-database-android/ because i didn't have any idea  how use spinner with a db. Right now i have a spinner that displays inside, the values written in the db (in my case Cibo e Bevande, trasporti, altro etc etc).. i just want display now in a textview what i choose from this spinner.. if i click `Cibo e bevande` the textview will display `Cibo e bevande`.. understand now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
String selecteditem = spinner.getselecteditem().tostring();
textview.settext(Selecteditem);
```

Comment: but in my case? `String NAME = spinner.getselecteditem().tostring();
categorietext.settext(NAME);`?

Comment: dude put this code in setonitemclicklistener method.whenever you select any item in spinner it will update the selected value in textview.

Answer (score 0):

Spinner have a default classes called setonitemselectedlistener(), in that we have a method named onItemSelected() in that method you can write this setting text value.